# NameNotFoundException while testing methods that need UserTransaction

Tags: java, jdbc, jboss, junit

I am retrieving the UserTransaction while doing some data insertions and the code works fine when running through the application in jboss. However it fails in JUnit tests when running with Ecplise saying

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name java:comp is not bound in this Context.
```

My Code to get the transaction is below

```
public static UserTransaction getUserTransation() throws CommonServiceException{
        Context context = null;
         UserTransaction ut = null;
        try {
            context = new InitialContext();
            ut = (UserTransaction)
            context.lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            throw new CommonServiceException(XMLReader.getErrorCode("Connector:getUserTransation"), e.getMessage(), e);
        }

          return ut;
    }
```

It cannot find the java:comp. Is there anything I should specifically do in my Junit test classes for me to get it work fine?

**Added:**

I added the below code to the test class and it didn't give the above mentioned error. But it failed later when doing the commit saying there is not transaction.

```
            ic = new InitialContext();

            ic.createSubcontext("java:");
            ic.createSubcontext("java:comp");
            ut = new UserTransactionImpl();  
            ic.bind("java:comp/UserTransaction",ut);
```

Comment: @Shri- jboss 4.2.3 GA and the application works fine. problem is in testing

Comment: How are you testing it? In container? Out of container?

Comment: If you are testing out of container, how is the user transaction to be provided to the test? The jndi namespace you are using is provided by jboss. How are you mocking it in your test environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can solve the issue by just creating a new UserTransactionImpl. A better way might be to create a mocked UserTransaction implementation and then bind *that* to jndi.

The one you are currently binding probably depends on other "magic" not available to it  out of container